# Deploy to only one role / server with capistrano

Tags: ruby, capistrano

I'm trying to set up multiple roles, one for live, and another for dev. They look like this:

```
role :live, "example.com"
role :dev, "dev.example.com"
```

When I run cap deploy, however, it executes for both servers. I've tried the following and it always executes on both.

```
cap deploy live
cap ROLE=live deploy
```

What am I missing? I know I can write a custom task that only responds to one role, but I don't want to have to write a whole bunch of tasks just to tell it to respond to one role or another. Thanks!

Comment: All of the answers below are confusing / incorrect.  ROLES does not act as a filter; rather it instructs capistrano to run all of the tasks on that role.  See https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/capistrano/4gTyvcAtyAg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try capistrano multistage:

http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2007/7/23/capistrano-multistage

Roles are intended to deploy different segments on different servers, as apposed to deploying the whole platform to just one set of servers.

Answer (score 14):

Capistrano Multistage is definitely the solution to the example you posted for deploying to environments. In regard to your question of deploying to roles or servers, Capistrano has command-line solutions for that too.

To deploy to a single role (notice ROLES is plural):

```
cap ROLES=web deploy
```

To deploy to multiple roles:

```
cap ROLES=app,web deploy
```

To deploy to particular server (notice HOSTS is plural):

```
cap HOSTS=web1.myserver.com deploy
```

To deploy to several servers:

```
cap HOSTS=web1.myserver.com,web2.myserver.com deploy
```

To deploy to a server(s) with a role(s):

```
cap HOSTS=web1.myserver.com ROLES=db deploy
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this:

```
task :dev do
    role :env, "dev.example.com"
end

task :prod do
    role :env, "example.com"
end
```

Then use:

```
cap dev deploy
cap prod deploy
```

Answer (score 2):

Just one more hint: if you use multistage remember to put ROLES constant before `cap` command.

```
ROLES=web cap production deploy
```

or after environment

```
cap production ROLES=web deploy
```

If you put as first parameter, multistage will treat it as stage name and replace with default one:

```
cap ROLES=web production deploy

* [...] executing `dev'
* [...] executing `production'
```